# Can ' functional' stress 'forced upon' a cell actually cause cell mutations when they divide and reproduce?

Tags: cell-biology, mutations, stress

If a group of cells are forced to go beyond their regular biological parameters that they should be under given ' healthy' functioning and while existing in these stressed states some of the cells divide and multiply would the added stressful states make them mutate?

Comment: On a tangent, lots of stressors abrogate division completely in healthy cells. One of the first things cells do in response to heat stress, for example, is stop pushing toward replication and begin transcribing [heat shock](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11389152) factors. [Compression can lead to cell cycle arrest](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/15/5586.full.pdf+html), and establishment of many cells in a given area leads to [contact inhibition of cell division](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/3/739.full).

Comment: Can prolonged exposure to various environmental toxins,even if in low doses, cause 'functional' stress on certain cells subject to the exposure and eventually abrogate cell division or accelerate it or cause it to operate unpredictably?

Comment: TL;DR Yes! I would take a look at how normal, healthy cells progress into [neoplasia](http://library.med.utah.edu/WebPath/NEOHTML/NEOPL104.html) and eventually cancer. Up to a certain point cells will undergo apoptosis, in effect dying before becoming "too abnormal," but one of the hallmarks of cancer is that the cell may somehow evade death (in addition to abnormal proliferation, etc.). Certainly, stressors which cause damage to the DNA (but not so much that the cells dies) are, at least over time, are going to begin to cause abnormalities in the tissues they affect.

Comment: Asbestos exposure comes to me as a good example: http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/csem/csem.asp?csem=29&po=10

Comment: If some type of 'functional stress' causes a cell or a group of cells to mutate and gain more and more mutations does this eventually cause the cell's apoptosis mechanisms to 'malfunction? Do some of these mutations 'interfere' with the functioning of the apoptosis 'mechanisms'?

Comment: Since it is a 'normal' cell ('before' 'functional stress' and any mutating ) that is gaining mutations does it have 'natural' abilities to avoid immune system attacks?  And if so these abilities that are within it and its 'progeny' when mutated help them to avoid immune system detection ; is this true?